# confusion power set and function mapping

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the set $S=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, define the mapping  $t: \mathcal{P}(S)\times \mathcal{P}(S) \to  \Bbb R$ by

$$
t((A,B))=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}~A=\emptyset~\text{or}~B=\emptyset,\\
|A \cap B| \left/ \sqrt{|A||B|}\right.&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Note that $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the power set of $S$.

**Question**: Determine the value of $t(\{a, b, d\},\{ b, c, d, e\})$.

I don't understand why power set has to do with function mapping. By the way I know that $\mathcal{P}(S)= 2^{|S|}$ ($|S|$ is the number of elements of $S$). Is this equation relevant in this exercise?

Comment: It's just the domain of the function. What does $\Bbb R$ have to do with the mapping? Why not $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb{Q_{alg}}$ or $\Bbb{Q_{alg}\cap R}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: Because the arguments of the function are subsets of $S$ i.e. elements of the *power-set* of $S$.

Comment: The function $t$ maps a *pair* of subsets to a number; that's all.

Comment: Also, the formula you mean is $|P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$, which means the *number of elements* in $P(S)$ is $2$ raised to the number of elements in $S$. $P(S)$ is the set of subsets of $S$, so the formula says there are $2^{|S|}$ subsets of $S$. (And that's not useful for the problem, no).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $P(S)$ is the set of all subsets of S.

For example, if $S = \{,\}$ then $P(S) = \{\emptyset,\{\},\{\},\{,\}\} $

So $P(S)\times P(S)$ means the set of every tuple $(A,B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are some subsets of $S$

Now for your question, $P(S)\times P(S)$ is the set that represent the domain of your function, just like $\mathbb{R}$ is the domain of the function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\: : f(x) = x^2$

this equality : $P(S)=2^{\text{(number of element in } S)}$ is false, but
$$\big(\text{number of element in } P(S)\big)=2^{(\text{number of element in } S)}$$ is true. Could you make a proof of it ?

Best of luck

Comment: To the proposer: Also $|A|$ denotes the number of members of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate $t$ at specific arguments $A, B$. So let

$$
A = \{a, b, d\},
B = \{ b, c, d, e\})
$$
and use the definition of $t$ with these values. You need to know three integers involving $A$ and $B$: determine $A \cap B$, and then its size $|A \cap B|$; determine $|A|, |B|$. Now compute the value of $t(A, B)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no essential or constant link between power set and function mapping; it simply happens you are dealing ***here***  with a function that is defined in this way.

A function has inputs and outputs.  The set of all inputs is the domain.

Here the domain is a set of pairs, namely the cartesian product of the set P(S)  ( that is, the power set of S).

Note : $ P(S) \times P(S)$ is the set of all possible ordered pairs having both a subset of S as first element and a subset of S as second element ( possibly the same subset, but  not in all cases).

It means that every input the function will take will be a pair of objects, and, ***in the special case you are dealing with***, these two ( ordered objects) are sets themselves.

Note that, while the inputs of the function are ordered pairs of sets , the outputs are not sets nor ordered pairs , but numbers.

Note : the distinction between sets and numbers is not absolute, since in some parts of mathematics, numbers are constructed as sets.